# how to convert numpy images into JPG images with their proper labels

Tags: python-3.x, image, numpy, image-processing, deep-learning

i have a "**images.npy**" file with about 2500 images and "**lebels.npy**" file with the images' proper labels(like: type_A, type_B, type_C, Type_B.......). I want to convert the numpy images into jpg images and save them into a directory with proper naming(names got from the labels.npy file). the directory will be like this:

- images

  - type_A

    - type_A1.jpg
    - type_A2.jpg
    - type_A3.jpg
  - type_B

    - type_B1.jpg
    - type_B2.jpg
    - type_B3.jpg
  - type_C

    - type_C1.jpg
    - type_C2.jpg
    - type_C3.jpg
  - type_D

    - type_D1.jpg
    - type_D2.jpg
    - type_D3.jpg
  - type_E

    - type_E1.jpg
    - type_E2.jpg
    - type_E3.jpg

so, how can I do that?

Comment: If your reading them all into memory then you can iterate through both at the same time using [zip](https://realpython.com/python-zip-function/)

Comment: The . npy format is the standard binary file format in NumPy for persisting a single arbitrary NumPy array on disk. The format stores all of the shape and dtype information necessary to reconstruct the array correctly even on another machine with a different architecture... without the inputs no idea on how to help you